# Reduce GroupedFlux in reactor

Tags: java, reactive-programming, project-reactor

I have one flux with distinct object types inside it that I want group elements by type and then reduce each group.

here is a trivial code to do this.

```
    Flux<Item> item=Flux.just(new Item("item1"), new Item("item2"));
    Flux<Item2> item2=Flux.just(new Item2(4.0f), new Item2(2.0f));

    Flux<Object> objects=Mono.empty().concatWith(item).concatWith(item2);       
    Flux<GroupedFlux<Object>> groups=objects.groupBy(value -> value.getClass());
```

How can I reduce each flow by type?`enter code here`

Answer (score 4):

I found the solution on the gitter.  Thanks to @simonbasle and @osi for reactiviy.

https://gitter.im/reactor/reactor

The key was the method flatMap and use the key to discrimine values.

```
groups.flatMap(gf -> {
        if(gf.key()==Item.class) {
            return gf.reduce(new Item(""), (a, b) -> {
                return new Item(a.getValue()+((Item)b).getValue());
            });
        }
        else if(gf.key()==Item2.class) {
            return gf.reduce(new Item2(0.0f), (a, b) -> {
                return new Item2(a.getValueF()+((Item2)b).getValueF());
            });
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("unknown key: "+gf.key());
    });
```